# How can SELECT UTC_TIMESTAMP() return -10:00 UTC?

Tags: mysql, timezone, timestamp, utc

Either I'm being stupid or something's wrong here.

I have two SQL Servers, the one is on my local machine (local time **+2 GMT**) and the other is somewhere else (`NOW()` seems to return **+8 GMT**)and I access it through phpMyAdmin. I have a table that has a `DATETIME` column. I'm trying

> to store the current **GMT/UTC** time and then display it again, still as GMT/UTC time.

Originally I stored `DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 8 HOUR)` which worked just fine. However, then I read about `UTC_TIMESTAMP()` and liked it more, as it was shorter and the [`MySQL manual`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time-zone-support.html) even said :

> "The current time zone setting does not affect values displayed by functions 
>   such as UTC_TIMESTAMP() or values in DATE, TIME, or DATETIME columns."

So perfect right? Except no.

Let's assume Current **GMT is 2010-02-18 17:18:17** (I even double checked it with someone in Britain).

On **my local (+2) server**, I get the following results for the following queries:

```
SELECT NOW(); 2010-02-18 19:18:17

SELECT UTC_TIMESTAMP(); 2010-02-18 17:18:17
```

On **my online server** I get:

```
SELECT NOW(); 2010-02-19 01:18:17

SELECT UTC_TIMESTAMP(); 2010-02-19 07:18:17 (WHY?!)
```

Am I missing something?!

Comment: i m suffering with same issue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Probably because the clock are wrong on the online server?

Try running this:

```
SELECT  @@system_time_zone, NOW(), UTC_TIMESTAMP()
```

and see which zone does it return and does it match the difference.

Comment: @@system_time_zone NOW() UTC_TIMESTAMP()
CST 2010-02-19 01:35:30 2010-02-19 07:35:30

So, if I'm understanding this right, the server says it's CST (-6) and it's set to 1:35am, so SQL's saying well then add 6 to get to UTC...

BAH! How frustrating.

Thanks for clearing it up, I thought I was doing something wrong it's been driving me insane.

Comment: Why is that frustrating? NOW() is the current time after timezone takes effect, so the functions are doing their job perfectly no?

Comment: @Alex I think MySQL logic/explanation makes complete sense, btw, so which one was not correct as per its timezone i.e. your local server or online server ?